# Is it possible with Stripe to show currency dynamically based on user's location (country)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm implementing Stripe checkout with Firebase cloud functions, my code looks like this:

```
 stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 500,
      currency: "usd",
      description: "lorem ipsum",
      source: token,
      statement_descriptor: "lorem ipsum"
 })
```

So I was wondering if there's a way to avoid the hard coded currency, and be able to do something like this:

```
      amount: user_amount,
      currency: user_currency
```

Where `user_amount` is the amount converted in the user's country currency and `user_currency` is the code corresponding to the user's country currency.

Has anyone done this before, or knows how it can be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are stored these values (user_amount and user_currency)? In the database? Passed when you call the Cloud Function (e.g. if is a callable Function)?

Comment: Those values are not stored anywhere, I used them as place holders because in the method above they are hard coded and that's what I want to avoid.   

And that's my problem by the way, I want to know if there are other options that **Stripe** offers or other techniques that would let me define the amount that I want to charge, before passing it to the `stripe.charges.create` method, so that every user will get charged in their **local currency**.

Comment: But the user_amount should come from somewhere, for example from the mobile or wep app the user is using, no?